# Import Error: no module named

Tags: python

Hi I'm VERY new to programming, and I am working on my first program. I've been following along in a book and I decided to stop and test a function. The function is in a file called `myPythonFunctions.py`. I then created a new file called `untitled.py` and put it in the same folder as `myPythonFunctions.py`.

In `untitled.py` I have the following code:

```
import myPythonFunctions as m
m.generateQuestion()
```

Very simple, but when I try to run it I get `Import Error: no module named myPythonFunctions`.

I don't understand, there is clearly a file named `myPythonFunctions` in the folder. What's going on?

In case you need it, here is the code for `m.generateQuestion()`

```
def generateQuestion():

    operandList = [0,0,0,0,0,]
    operatorList = ['', '', '', '', '']
    operatorDict = [1:'+', 2:'-', 3:'*', 4:'**']

    for index in range(0,5):
        operandList[index] = randint(1,9)

    for index in range(0,4):
        if index > 0 and operatorList[index-1] !='**':

            operator = operatorDict[randint(1,4)]
        else:

            operator = operatorDict[randint(1,3)]

    operatorList[index] = operator
    questionString = str(operandList[0])

    for index in range(1,5):
        questionString = questionString + OperatorList[index-1] + str[operandList[index]

    result = eval(questionString)
    questionString.replace("**","^")
    print('\n' + questionString)
    userAnswer=input('Answer: ')
    while true:
        try:
            if int(userAnswer) == result:
                print('Correct!')
                return 1
            else:
                print('Sorry, the correct answer is', result)
                return 0
        except Exception as e:
                print("That wasn't a number")
                userAnswer = input('Answer: ')
```

**Edit: I'm now getting this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Brad/Desktop/Python/Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myPythonFunctions as m
  File "/Users/Brad/Desktop/Python/myPythonFunctions.py", line 33
    operatorDict = [1:'+', 2:'-', 3:'*', 4:'**']
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please check your indentation in your code here. `def generateQuestion():` should have indented lines after it. Is that an error in how you wrote this question, or is your indentation really like that in the code?

Comment: Are you running `untitled.py` (I would suggest a more specific name) from the current working directory?

Comment: the def generateQuestion( ): Is indented in the real code. It just copied weird. I didn't plan on actually using untitled.py, I just wanted to test my function.

Comment: Sounds like you've gotten the import to work, and now have a different issue. Syntax errors are generally an indicator of a typo or incorrect understanding of the Python grammar, so please check it carefully before asking a new question about it.

Comment: For your specific syntax error, the data structure you're creating doesn't conform to any single known type. I recommend taking a look at the official Python tutorial's [section on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html) to see how they are formed.

Comment: Please, don't edit/add new issues in the sames question, just create a separated question for the new problem. The new error you are getting is because you are trying to define a dictionary with square brackets instead of brackets.

Comment: Can you add which version of python you're using? (Importing differs slightly between python 2 and python 3)

Answer (score 0):

The syntaxis error you are getting, is because you are trying to define a dictionary as a list, so the interpreter is raising the error because it does not know what to do with that.

To define a dictionary you need to use { } instead of [ ]

Answer (score -2):

## --- EDIT 2

Your dictionary implementation is wrong, do you really copied this code from somewhere?

The

```
operatorDict = {1:'+', 2:'-', 3:'*', 4:'**'}
```

Your code was mispelled

## ---- EDIT

Your code on **myPythonFunctions** is really bad.

Python **needs** correct identation to works, please double check this step

---

I suggest you to do a check in your structure:

I did this right now

```
/somefolder
--this.py
--functions.py
/
```

The contents
--this.py

```
import functions as f

print f.hello()
```

--functions.py

```
def hello():
    return 'It worked'
```

Try this structure in your environment :D

And then run:

```
python this.py
```

Comment: The OP edited their question saying that the import now works. I don't know what they changed.

Comment: Just saw that, and edited my answer as well, thanks :D

Comment: The OP said they have both files in the same folder, which is all you're telling them to do. This doesn't answer the question. The OP also said that the indentation in their post doesn't match the indentation in their actual code.

Comment: Im starting to think that the OP just copied this code from somewhere really wrong, or is using an outdated python version. Pretty weird

Comment: This answer is targeting other problems but not the main question of the OP, which is: why the import statement isn't working. You should've fixed those problems yourself by editing and/or leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry to tell @KurzedMetal but my answer targets the OP's main question AND the other issues he encountered. But I really didn't get why I was downvoted...